# Highlighter is not detecting when i try to automate notepad using Karate robot

Tags: karate

I'm trying to automate Notepad and trying to click on Maximize and minimize buttons, but the highlighter is not detecting the notepad size correctly.

[highlighter screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0YIw.jpg)

[Trying to Click on maximize screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOmYF.jpg)

Below is my code:

Feature: notepad testing

Scenario:

- robot { window: '^Notepad', fork: 'notepad', highlight: true }

  - delay(5000)
  - click('//button{Maximize}')
  - click('//button{Minimize}')
  - input('karate dsl' + Key.ENTER)

I have used accessibility insights to locate elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to work-around and change your Windows resolution to something that works.